# Can I safely downgrade an encrypted Asus Transformer TF101 from 8.6.5.21 to 8.6.5.19?

Tags: rooting, backup, encryption, downgrade

I want to root my encrypted Asus Transformer TF101 (Firmware 8.6.5.21; Serial B80...) and install a custom ROM. I read that the only way to do this is by [downgrading to stock 8.6.5.19](http://www.transformerforums.com/forum/asus-transformer-development/11783-confirmed-fix-gain-root-after-8-6-5-21-update.html) and then using [Razorclaw](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1345049).

I know that using tablet encryption with Custom ROMs is a [big no-no](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=21542042), so I will have to wipe my data (factory reset). However I do wish to keep some application Data (such as save games) to which I only have access via root.

So my question is, can I:

1. Safely(!) downgrade to 8.6.5.19 on my encrypted tablet
2. root
3. backup
4. unencrypt the tablet (factory reset)
5. install custom ROM

or do I have to:

1. factory reset (losing all my precious data)
2. downgrade to 8.6.5.19
3. root
4. install custom ROM

**Update:**
I found out that Asus already includes an app which allows to save application data without root (aptly named "App Backup"). So I will go with the second option. I'll leave the question open though as I still don't know if I could have downgraded without doing a factory reset.

Comment: I know some tablets can be upgraded while encrypted, so it would make sense if downgrading was possible also.  Is there an "official" method to downgrade, though?

Comment: not really, the downgrade itself is a hack of sorts, it gives the old firmware with a higher version number (see first link). The process should be similar to a regular upgrade so I am hoping it works, Id just rather someone who knows confrims it ;-)

Comment: Interesting.  Speaking personally, I'd risk it.  You don't have much of an option unless your current firmware is rootable, right?

Comment: Well I could go with option 2... I'd rather loose my save games than brick my tablet.

Comment: Fair enough.  Hopefully you get an answer.

Comment: So any progress on this? Would be nice to know whether one of the solutions worked (flawlessly). You could answer your own question and accept it -- the community will appreciate this :)

Comment: sure thing - I dont want to mess up the statistics ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing a factory reset on my tablet (after doing a backup of my data with "App Backup"). As far as I know the downgrade would probably have worked, but I decided not to risk it.